# SQL How to sum a column for a unique pair of keys

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I couldn't figure how to do this. I would like to sum a coulmn called "total_spending" for similar pairs (vin, action) and choose the first dealer_name and reference month year (so it won't create duplicates) and have an output like the example:
Input

```
action  dealer_name   vin    Total_spending reference month year 
A1      D1            V1         T1             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T2             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T3             R2     M2    Y2
A3      D2            V1         T4             R1     M1    Y1
A4      D1            V2         T5             R1     M1    Y1
A2      D1            V2         T6             R1     M1    Y1
A1      D1            V1         T7             R2     M2    Y2
A4      D1            V2         T8             R2     M2    Y2
A1      D1            V1         T9             R3     M3    Y3
A3      D2            V2         T10            R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V1         T11            R2     M2    Y2
```

output

```
action  dealer_name   vin    Total_spending reference month year 
A1      D1            V1         T1 + T7 + T9   R1     M1    Y1
A2      D2            V2         T2 + T3        R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V1         T4 + T11       R1     M1    Y1
A4      D1            V2         T5 + T8        R1     M1    Y1
A2      D1            V2         T6             R1     M1    Y1
A3      D2            V2         T10            R1     M1    Y1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select action,dealer_name,vin,sum(Total_spending) as total_spending, reference ,month, year
from tablename
group by action,  dealer_name ,  vin,reference ,month, year
```

Comment: Hello @Fahmi , I tried it didn't work, it won't sum the value of total_spending for the similar action and vin

Comment: @Jinx_man, can you post what you output you are getting then and your table structure? This solution should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, It worked, first it didn't because the month was not the same for similar vin, action